# Can someone help me with this MySQL code?

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve some date from 2 different tables action and staff.

This is my code:

```
SELECT ActionID, FeedbackID, StaffID, ActionDate, ActionDetails,
       (SELECT StaffName, Department 
        FROM staff 
        WHERE staff.StaffID=action.StaffID) 
FROM action;
```

I am getting this error:

> #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error comes from having two outputs in the SELECT sub-query.

Solution:
Having 1 sub-query per output should work if each only returns one value.

Warning:
If your sub-query returns multiple outputs, you'll receive an error. Thus, it is best practice to use SELECT sub-queries for known single outputs, like COUNT or SUM.

For multiple outputs:
Please use joins, for example:

```
SELECT a.ActionID, a.FeedbackID, a.StaffID, a.ActionDate, a.ActionDetails
, b.staffName, b.department

FROM action a
LEFT JOIN staff b on a.staffid=b.staffid
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to inner join the two tables on their Primary Keys.  Does this run for you:

CODE:

```
SELECT 
    A.ActionID, A.FeedbackID, A.StaffID, A.ActionDate, A.ActionDetails,
    S.StaffName, S.Department

FROM Action AS A
    INNER JOIN Staff AS S ON Action.ActionID = Staff.ActionID
```